# Limit jQuery Cookie Plugin to 1 hour

Tags: jquery, cookies, plugins

I am creating a cookie using the jQuery cookie plugin. I want to limit it to 1 hour, instead of 1 day. Through the docs the lowest value that it gives an example of is 1 day. How can I lessen this value from 1 day, to 1 hour?

```
jQuery.cookie('data', data, { expires: 1 }); // this limits to 1 day
```

I came across this with just plan javascript, but It didn't seem to work for me with the plugin. Comes back with `time() is not defined`

```
jQuery.cookie('data', data, { expires:  time()+3600 }); // this limits to 1 day
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `Date` object with the date of expiration

```
jQuery.cookie('data', data, {
    expires: new Date(+new Date() + (60 * 60 * 1000))
});
```